# Azure cli - Failed to connect to MSI

Tags: azure-cli

How do I solve this error?

```
az account get-access-token --resource https://cognitiveservices.azure.com                                        
Failed to connect to MSI. Please make sure MSI is configured correctly.
Get Token request returned: <Response [400]>
```

Comment: Are you on your local computer or in an Azure resource?

Comment: Try connecting to Azure with `az login` first and then run `az account get-access-token --resource https://cognitiveservices.azure.com`.

Comment: @florian - azure cli

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I ran same command as you in Azure Cloud Shell, I got **same error** as below:

```
az account get-access-token --resource https://cognitiveservices.azure.com
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, you need to run `az login` first and connect with **vaild** identity(user account) like below:

```
az login --only-show-errors
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I ran below command again after signing in with **valid** user account, I got **access token** successfully like this:

```
az account get-access-token --resource https://cognitiveservices.azure.com
```

**Response:**

[image]

I executed the same commands in my **local** environment too and got an access token successfully like below:

```
az login
az account show
az account get-access-token --resource https://cognitiveservices.azure.com
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, check how you are connecting to Azure from CLI and make sure to sign in with **valid** identity while running `az login`.